# Resizing an array to another shape in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, resize, reshape

I have the following array:

```
a = np.random.rand(5,2)
a

array([[0.98736372, 0.07639041],
       [0.45342928, 0.4932295 ],
       [0.75789786, 0.48546238],
       [0.85854235, 0.74868237],
       [0.13534155, 0.79317482]])
```

and I want to resize it so that it is divided into 2 batches with three elements (adding zeros as required):

```
array([[[0.98736372, 0.07639041],
       [0.45342928, 0.4932295 ],
       [0.75789786, 0.48546238]],
       [[0.85854235, 0.74868237],
       [0.13534155, 0.79317482],
       [0, 0]]])
```

I have tried this, but it returns None:

```
a = a.copy()
a.resize((2,3,2), refcheck = False)
```

I believe .reshape would not provide the solution, as it is not able to fill in with 0's to comply with the desired dimensions for the array.

Comment: Did you recheck the `resize` method's docs?  Why the copy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using numpy.resize, you have to use like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(5,2)
b = np.resize(a, (2,3,2))
```

otherwise you can use the object method to get the same result, like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(5,2)
a.np.resize(2,3,2)
b = a.copy()
```

note the first one return `ndarray` and the last one returns None because It changes the object itself. For more info, look the [numpy.resize doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html)

Comment: Thank you! Only the object method works when removing np from a.np.resize(shape). The first method does not work (the documentation raises the fact that np.resize(shape) is not the same as a.resize(shape).